# Jquery .load firing twice, but being called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem here, my jquery .load function seems to be running twice even though Im only calling it once. Here is my code:

```
function updateRowItem(idIn){
if (ready) {
    id = idIn
    $("#controlPanelResult").css("background-color", "");
    var query = {};

    var tid = id.replace("@", "\\@");
    tid = tid.replace(".", "\\.");

    var value =  $('#'+tid).text();

    //var value =  decodeURI(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);

    //if (value == "<br>"){
    //  value = "NULL"
    //}
    //value = value.replace("&nbsp;"," ")
    //value = value.replace("&amp;","&")

    var split = id.split('@');
    var temp = split[0];
    var uuid = split[1];
    var temp2 = temp.split('.');
    var tableName = temp2[0];
    var item = temp2[1];

    query['table_name'] = tableName;
    query['uuid'] = uuid;
    query[item] = value;

    var tid = id.replace("@", "\\@");
    tid = tid.replace(".", "\\.");

    $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    //url: '/admin/updateRow?table_name=' + tableName + "&uuid=" + uuid +"&" +     item + "=" + value,
    url: '/admin/updateRow',
    data: query,
    success: function(data) {
            if (data == "1"){ 

                alert ("Hellooo!")//This alert only and always pops up once

                    $('#'+tid).empty().load(showRowsUrl + " #" + tid,function (status) { 
                        alert (status) // This alert pops up first once, then twice, then four times, then eight etc....

                        $("#"+tid).animate({backgroundColor: '#70DB70'}, 'slow');
                        $('#controlPanelResult').html("Updated: " + id);
                        $("#controlPanelResult").animate({ backgroundColor: '#70DB70'}, 'slow');
                        $("#"+tid).animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 'slow');
                    });

            } else {
                $('#mainRows').load(showRowsUrl, function() {
                    $("#"+tid).animate({backgroundColor: 'red'}, 'fast');
                    $('#controlPanelResult').html(data);
                    $("#controlPanelResult").animate({backgroundColor: 'red'}, 'fast'); 
                });
            }               
        }
    });
}
}
```

This causes my divs contents to be constantly repeated, I would appreciate any help in figuring this out

Comment: what do you mean by `if(ready)`?

Comment: @MarkEirich did you guess? it's not the culprit.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling it only once? How do you call `updateRowItem()`?

Comment: @Juhana its called like this onblur="updateRowItem(id)"

Comment: If it were called multiple times then "Hellooo!" would appear multiple times, but it does not.

Comment: This is from the jquery demo $('#b').load('article.html #target'); at http://api.jquery.com/load/ . They do mention somthing about script execution when doing a load with a specific div...

Comment: Is it possible that the server's response contains JS which causes this to re-run?

Comment: In Chromes 'network' view, it only does one load, and then "helloooo" pops up once, and then the alert(status) pops up 2,4,8

Comment: If I replace $('#'+tid).empty().load(showRowsUrl + " #" + tid,function (status)   with $('#mainRows').load(showRowsUrl,function (status), the status alert only pops up one time per call, as I would expect. Im basicly updating a table, and every time there is a change in a cell (as a div), I want to refresh just that div, not the entire table

Comment: Does it behave any differently if, instead of using `.load()`, you use `.get()` and then set the content of the row in the callback?

Comment: @Mark Eirich If I do that I get an entire table in the td/cell that I wanted to update. I dont think that .get can load in just a specific divs content like: $.get(showRowsUrl + " #" + tid, function(data) {

Comment: You're probably right. At this point your best bet is to reduce this problem by removing any unrelated JS and HTML.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13258/discussion-between-mark-eirich-and-jr93)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the problematic `.load()` call with this:

```
$.get(showRowsUrl, function(data) {
    $('#'+tid).replaceWith($('#'+tid,'<div>'+data+'</div>'));

    $("#"+tid).animate({backgroundColor: '#70DB70'}, 'slow');
    $('#controlPanelResult').html("Updated: " + id);
    $("#controlPanelResult").animate({ backgroundColor: '#70DB70'}, 'slow');
    $("#"+tid).animate({backgroundColor: 'white'}, 'slow');
});
```

Explanation: `.load` is loading the element into itself, so there are afterwards two elements with the same ID, nested. Then when you run `.load` again, it runs on both elements with that ID, and so on.

Comment: Yes, I just came to the same conclusion.